# When backup size exceeds its limit triggers an email to the users

Tags: email

Am taking the daily backup using task scheduler and saved in local folder so my requirement is whenever the backup is exceeds its limit (for eg:we fix it 500 mb) and if exceeds more than 500mb  so it sends an email to the user.HOw it can be possible.Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a detail or two missing: What language? What environment? Etc.

But, as a possible example:

```
$backupFilePath = 'path to your backup file';
$limit = your limit in bytes;
if (filesize($backupFilePath) < $limit) {
  //log?
} else {
  $to = "someone@example.com";
  $subject = "Limit Exceeded";
  $message = "Limit of ".$limit". bytes exceeded.";
  $from = "someonelse@example.com";
  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: Hi Brad, Currently am using this code but it returns only size of one subfolder,I want to print size of each subfolder one by one.

Comment: Is the number of subfolders dynamic? Or is there just a static set of subfolders that need to be checked? You could put the filepaths of the subfolders into an array and loop though the array running the code above for each subfolder.